# parentNode being lost on Javascript inner closure? Chrome bug?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, garbage-collection, closures

When I execute the below test HTML page in Chrome, I see the following in the debug console:

```
Has parent? true
Has parent? false
```

Am I right in assuming that this a Chrome bug (it doesn't happen in other browsers), or is Chrome within its right to do this for some reason? It resulted in a bug in one of my web apps and I finally isolated this snippet to repro the core issue.

Here is the test page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body class="">
      
      
      <script>
        function testDoodle() {
          var testParentEl = document.createElement('div');
          var testChildEl  = testParentEl.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
          
          document.body.innerHTML+=('Has parent? ' + !!testChildEl.parentNode+'<br>');
          console.log('Has parent? ' + !!testChildEl.parentNode);
          
          setTimeout(function() {
              document.body.innerHTML+=('Has parent? ' + !!testChildEl.parentNode+'<br>');
              console.log('Has parent? ' + !!testChildEl.parentNode);
          },
          2000);
          return;
        }
        testDoodle();
      </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

EDIT: I should have mentioned that I'm testing on Windows 7 with Chrome 49.0.2623.87 m (64-bit). Was also able to repro on OSX 10.11.2 with Chrome 49.

Also, I should mention that sometimes it displays true/true and sometimes true/false. You might have to reload the page a few times to witness the issue. I'm not sure, but it's possible that the debug tools (console) need to be open as well.

Thanks much.

Comment: Works for me in Chrome 48 OSX

Comment: I cannot reproduce (Chrome 48.0.2564.109). Are you sure that the `testParentEl` is not mutated between the calls?

Comment: I should have mentioned that I'm testing on Windows 7 with Chrome 49.0.2623.87 m (64-bit).

Also, I should mention that sometimes it displays true/true and sometimes true/false. You might have to reload the page a few times to witness the issue. I'm not sure, but it's possible that the debug tools (console) need to be open as well.

Comment: Same issue for me on the same browser version (Windows 10)

Comment: Updated to Chrome 49 and still cannot reproduce.

Comment: I just tried this again on OSX (10.11.2) with the latest version of Chrome (64-bit) and was still able to repro, so this is not a Windows-specific issue.

All I did was hit the Run Code Snippet button on this page, but note that I had to do it twice before the issue repro'ed. (The first time it showed true/true, and the second time it showed true/false).

Comment: Weird, wanted to bisect the problem but I can no longer reproduce it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that this is finally fixed by Chrome v50 (or at least I haven't been able to repro since updating).

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `testChildEl.parentNode` does not reference `testParentEl` strongly, so it's garbage collected.

Both referencing `testParentEl` inside the timeout and adding a strong reference to `testParentEl` on `testChildEl` fix the problem for me:

```js
(function testDoodle() {
  var testParentEl = document.createElement('div');
  var testChildEl  = testParentEl.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
  setTimeout(function() {
    testParentEl; // Prevents it from being garbage collected
    document.write('Has parent? ' + !!testChildEl.parentNode);
  }, 100);
})();
```

```js
(function testDoodle() {
  var testParentEl = document.createElement('div');
  var testChildEl  = testParentEl.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
  testChildEl.strongParent = testParentEl; // Prevents garbage collection
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.write('Has parent? ' + !!testChildEl.parentNode);
  }, 100);
})();
```

Comment: This really sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: Are there already a such thing as "strong" and "weak" references in Javascript? My understanding was that there are not. I too discovered that the problem could be fixed by having an explicit reference to testPartEl from within the closure.

Yes, I'm convinced it's a bug. Clearly some Chrome optimization gone bad. I'm just not sure why no one else seems to be bit by it.

Comment: @logidelic ES6 introduces WeakSets and WeakMaps, which store weak references to objects. Apart from this it's all implementation-dependent, the spec doesn't require a garbage collector. Bu definition, it shouldn't be possible to detect whether an object has been garbage collector, so this is a bug.